# Convert href link to image link use with thumbshots

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have seen some good scripts come by but not one i really could use.
My website is php sql driven and i like to change the links on the site with a image
from thumbshots.
The code i have so far is:

```
<a href="<?php echo $link['url'] ;?>"><?php echo openld_htmlspecialchars($link['title']); ?></a>
```

And as far as the script i have go like:

```
$('.post-body a').each(
    function(){
        $('<img />').attr('src','http://open.thumbshots.org/image.aspx?url='+encodeURIComponent(this.href)).replaceAll($(this));
    });
```

I used the .replaceAll function but it shows only the pictures and are not click links.
I used .insertAfter but then the text link keeps showing.

It's probably not a huge change in the script code but i don't seem to find the answer on my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope that what you are looking for ...

```
$('.post-body a').each(function(){
    $(this).html("<img src='http://open.thumbshots.org/image.aspx?url="+encodeURIComponent(this.href)">");
});
```

Comment: But where does this go? http://open.thumbshots.org/image.aspx?url='+encodeURIComponent

Comment: Thanks for your fast responds, i will check it out right away.

Comment: No it's not working, i probably do something wrong i will test the code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I have found a very simple solution. Normal u use <a href="http://google.com">Google</a> Now if u use only <a href="http://google.com"></a> with no text between the a tags and the you should use this part of jquery

$('.post-body a').each(
function(){
    $('<img />').attr('src','http://open.thumbshots.org/image.aspx?url='+ this.href).appendTo($(this));
});

Then it will generate the complete list only with the images from thumbshots

Thanks Hulk for your help.